# Google Maps not showing in Ionic Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm trying to show the google map in an ionic modal but it doesnt show up..but when i show it on page it shows up.Please i need some help regarding this.Its very annoying. Below in my controler js and ionic modal.

```js
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/mapmodal.html', {
          scope: $scope,
          animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function(modal) {
          $scope.modal4 = modal;
        });

      $scope.openmapModal = function()
      {
          
         $scope.modal4.show();
      };

      $scope.closemapModal = function() { 
        $scope.modal4.hide();
      };     

 var posOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 0
        };
        
$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
            var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log(lat); 
            console.log(long); 
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            $scope.openmapModal();    
            //var jus = document.getElementById('map');
//            var map;
            $scope.initMap = function() {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                console.log('entered map');
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    draggable: true,
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: $scope.map,
                    title: "Your location"
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {


                    document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
                    document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
                });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", $scope.initMap());
            
            });
```

```html
<ion-modal-view >
  <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="common-header">
    <h1 class="title">Add address</h1>
     <button class="button button-icon icon ion-close" ng-click="modal4.hide();"></button>    
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark">
      <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
  </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: have you defined $ionicModel in controller.js like *.controller('AppCtrl', function($ionicModal) { //your code }*

Comment: yes!! i have defined it....I already have 2 more modals in the same view all working fine

Comment: which one is your line no 24? and from where $scope.initMap() starts ?

Comment: @Atula on line 24 m using cordovageolocation to get the lat and lang and then passing it to the google map to show it on the map. It runs fine in the view but it does not run in modal

Comment: hard to figure . Does  $scope.openmapModal();  work properly ?

Comment: yes it opens up the modal..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113507/discussion-between-atula-and-talentedandrew).

Comment: @Atula ok lets join there

Comment: In the opened modal, do you happen to see a gray area where map was supposed to be? What is your `map` div css? Can you show the implementation of `modal4.show()` function?

Comment: no grey area only blank area...and proper map css is there because it was working fine in other views..just not working in a modal

Comment: @MatejP. can you tell me how to access the element which is inside the modal from the controller because document.getElementById returns null..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that `$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then` is being run before the HTML template `templates/mapmodal.html` is loaded. That way the elements you are trying to retrieve using `document.getElementById` don't exist yet. Try to call the code after the html is loaded. Also include some timeout to make sure the modal is already shown when initialising the map (alternatively you can watch for `modal.shown` event).

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/mapmodal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal4 = modal;
      $scope.openmapModal();
      setTimeout(function(){//here!
          getPositionAndShowOnMap(); 
      }, 500);
    });

  $scope.openmapModal = function()
  {
     $scope.modal4.show();
  };

  $scope.closemapModal = function() { 
    $scope.modal4.hide();
  };     

function getPositionAndShowOnMap(){
    var posOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
        var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(lat);
        console.log(long);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.initMap = function() {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            console.log('entered map');
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                draggable: true,
                position: myLatlng,
                map: $scope.map,
                title: "Your location"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {


                document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
            });
        };
        $scope.initMap();
    });
}
```

Comment: yeah!! the problem was that it was not getting the map elemnt...so called it after opening the modal

Comment: Glad I was able to help.