# Google Maps doesn't show up in a Modal Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've been integrating Google maps to my ionic app by following https://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-google-maps-with-an-ionic-application/
this tutorial. I've integrated the map to a view without issues and it's detecting the location. But when I try to add the map into an modal I'm getting blank modal without a map in it.

I've checked [Google Maps not showing in Ionic Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565571/google-maps-not-showing-in-ionic-modal) , and as I'm loading the map after the HTML template is loaded I don't think it will be helpful.

This is my modal code which includes map.

```
<script id="location.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view>
        <ion-content>
          <div>
            <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
          </div>       
          <button class="button button-block button-dark " ng-click="closeModal()"> Close</button>
        </ion-content>

      </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
```

This is my controller code which I use to open the modal.

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('location.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
 }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
 });

  $scope.detectLocation = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
    $scope.loadgooglemap();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
  // Execute action on hide modal
  $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  // Execute action on remove modal
  $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
    // Execute action
  });

  $scope.loadgooglemap = function(){
    var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    //Wait until the map is loaded
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function(){

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: $scope.map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: latLng
      });      

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "Here I am!"
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
      });

    });
    }, function(error){
      console.log("Could not get location");
    });

  }
```

I'm not getting any error when I open the modal. Just getting the modal with the Close button(which I've included in the modal).

What might be the reason the map isn't loading in the modal. What have I done wrong? Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: I'm guessing the map works outside of the modal? I had a similar thing yesterday with google maps (not in a modal, but it wouldn't show - there was just a blank space instead). See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605593/google-map-container-shows-with-no-map

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS rule:

```
ion-app._gmaps_cdv_ .ion-page:not(._gmaps_cdv_),
ion-app._gmaps_cdv_ ion-modal:not(._gmaps_cdv_) {
    display: none;
}
```

In modal Component:

```
ionViewWillLeave() {

    const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('._gmaps_cdv_');

    for (let k = 0; k < nodeList.length; ++k) {
        nodeList.item(k).classList.remove('_gmaps_cdv_');
    }
}
```